# Webpack doesn't load the JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to make a simple application where I use Webpack and babel.
Down below you could find the code that I've writed...
Unfortunately ,launching npm run start, from the browser console does not give me any error and the file (index.js) does not work;

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

That's HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Canvas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root" ></div>
    <script type="text/js"  src="../src/index.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Babel:

```
{
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "edge": "17",
            "firefox": "60",
            "chrome": "67",
            "safari": "11.1"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Webpack:

```
// Plugins
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // Main
    mode: 'development',
    devtool:'inline-source-map',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'./dist'),
        filename: 'main.bundle.js',
        clean:true,
    },
    // Loaders
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    "presets":['@babel/preset-env']}
                }
            },
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use:['style-loader','css-loader'],
            }
        ]},
    // HTML
    plugins:[new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename:'main.bundle.html',
        template:path.join(__dirname,'public','index.html'),
    })],
    // Development Server 
    devServer:{
        hot:true,
        open:true,
        port:8080,
        compress:true,
        liveReload:true,
    }
  };
```

index.js:

```
alert('hello world!');
console.log('hello world!')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `script` tag (`<script type="text/js"  src="../src/index.js" ></script>`) in your `index.html` since `HTMLWebpackPlugin` is responsible for injecting it in your HTML file. Bundling it with Webpack you are also renaming it in `main.bundle.js` (in your output configuration).

Comment: I've tried to remove the script tag, launch again `npm run build` and `npm run start` but doesn't work.... Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for answering, I found your answer very interesting and I learned a new thing, I solved it by adding things that I had forgotten

Comment: @Leonardo, what things specifically?

Comment: The question is closed